# Java how to see if a String contains multiple words?

Tags: java, string

My question is, how can I tell if the html contains anything in the string, the below doesn't work. it throws, incompatible types: java.lang.String[]

```
    public void run() {
        Document doc;
        String[] matches = new String[]{"Unavailable", "Too Short", "skin-3d"};
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt", true));
            //Thread.sleep(3000);
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://t.com/s/" + line).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com").ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();
            //Elements ID = doc.getElementsByClass("card-header");
            String html = doc.html();
            if (!html.contains(matches)) {
                System.out.println(line + " taken");
                System.out.println(line + " is available or is only two chars");
                writer.write(line + "\n");
                writer.close();

            } else {
                System.out.println(line + " taken");
                writer.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: just to be clear you want to check if html contains all the String in the array matches or at least one?

Comment: Yes correct but something like GhostCat's answer is spamming the website 3 times which times me out

Comment: what is correct? all match or only one match?

Comment: What i'm basically trying to do is, if {"Unavailable", or "Too Short" or "skin-3d" is in the html then..

Comment: ok so it is any match

Answer (score 2):

The contains method takes only **one** argument; which must a single **CharSequence**.

You try to pass an **array** of strings instead.

So one easy solution would be to change that to:

```
boolean anyMatch = false;
for (String match : matches) {
  if (html.contains(match)) {
   anyMatch = true;
```

and later on check `anyMatch`.

For the record: this is really basic. And the compiler told you **exactly** what the problem with your code is. When you get a compiler message ... then **read** it. Read the javadoc for the library methods you are calling. Search the net for parts of your error message. That is how you resolve such problems!

Comment: This did not work for me, I am now getting refused connection since I am connecting three times.

Comment: Of course you have to make that change in place. And seriously: if such easy things give you so many problems: consider stepping back and learning some more basics right **now**. Don't play around with http connections, file readers and such things if you are unable to take my piece of example code and put that at the correct place in your source code. In other words: it is your code, you have to make sure that you calling connect() and html() just once!

Answer (score 0):

From the Java API

> **boolean**   **contains(CharSequence s)**
>
> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.

You cannot give an array of String to the contains method but one String.
I suggest you to do a for loop to solve your problem:

```
boolean match = false;
for (String s : matches){ 
    if (html.contains(s)){
        match = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is the same as GhostCat answer, if you have nothing new, then no need to have a duplicate answer. Just you can vote up the answer that you think is right for this question. Thanks

Comment: First of all, I was writing my answer at the same time. Secondly I think the reference to the Java API is really important. It shows people that researches can be made upfront asking a question and it often the best way to find answers. Finally my solution seems to be a bit quicker as it stops the loop once any element found.

Comment: If only for stopping loop you re-answered the question, then it was better to edit the first answer or leave a comment, anyway there is nothing new in your answer just copying and pasting.

Comment: Please read my comment again. Thanks.

Comment: I have read your comment, you are the best and the most profession person in Java in the world. Just keep on copy and paste, good luck for you!

Comment: Lack of arguments. It ends here.